# Ruby on Rails. dispatch.fcgi . dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- fcgi (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, fastcgi, mod-fastcgi

app = redmine-2.0.1
ruby = ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-linux]

```
[root@by1016690 public]# ./dispatch.fcgi
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require': iconv will be deprecated in the future, use String#encode instead.
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- fcgi (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/fastcgi.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from ./dispatch.fcgi:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The *fcgi* handler is not part of the *Redmine* core.
In order to use it you have to add it to your *Gem* dependencies.

Create a file called '*Gemfile.local*' in your Redmine installation with:

```
# Gemfile.local
gem "fcgi"
```